# React Native Expo: Network error on android

Tags: android, react-native, axios, fetch, general-network-error

I'm using axios in my app. When I make a post request for the very first time after opening the app, it is failing with the following error. From second time onwards, it works without any issue.

```
Network Error
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:81:22 in handleError
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I'm running on a real android device connecting to a real server by http://my_ip:my_port/. Same post request I tried by creating a Native android project in kotlin, and it is working without any issue

Here is my code:

```
const upload = () => {
    setAnalyzing(true);

    axios.post(URL_PREDICT, formBody(), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }).then(handleSuccess)
      .catch(handleFail);
  }

  const formBody = () => {
    const photo = {
      uri: image,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'photo.jpg',
    };
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", photo);
    return form;
  };

  const handleFail = (error) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(error?.response?.data);
    setAnalyzing(false);
    toggle();
    alert("ERROR " + error);
  };

  const handleSuccess = response => {
    console.log('success...');
    setAnalyzing(false);
    toggle();
    console.log(response);
    navigation.navigate('Result', response);
  };
```

Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: `http` might be the issue here. Try using `https` with a valid domain certificate. Also please share your `package.json`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are using `expo-image-picker`.

There are two independent issues at action here. Let’s say we get `imageUri` from `image-picker`, then we would use these following lines of code to upload from the frontend.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', {
 uri : imageUri,
 type: "image",
 name: imageUri.split("/").pop()
});
```

The first issue is with the `imageUri` itself. If let’s say photo path is `/user/.../path/to/file.jpg`. Then file picker in android would give `imageUri` value as `file:/user/.../path/to/file.jpg` whereas file picker in iOS would give `imageUri` value as `file:///user/.../path/to/file.jpg`.

The solution for the first issue is to use `file://` instead of `file:` in the formData in android.

The second issue is that we are not using the proper `mime-type`. It is working fine on iOS but not on Android. What makes this worse is that the file-picker package gives the type of the file as “image” and it does not give proper mime-type.

The solution is to use proper `mime-type` in the formData in the field type. Ex: mime-type for `.jpg` file would be `image/jpeg` and for `.png` file would be `image/png`. We do not have to do this manually. Instead, you can use a very famous npm package called [mime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime).

The final working solution is:

```
import mime from "mime";

const newImageUri =  "file:///" + imageUri.split("file:/").join("");

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', {
 uri : newImageUri,
 type: mime.getType(newImageUri),
 name: newImageUri.split("/").pop()
});
```

Comment: That uri difference in android and ios has resolved I guess, because the uri in my android is already starts with "file:///"

Answer (score 10):

## Solution 1

Make Sure **"http://"** is in your URL Address .

1. change from **localhost** to your **ip**
2. add **http://**

http://192.168.43.49:3000/user/

## Solution 2

I faced same issue, it happens in Android, but works well in IOS.
I guess this issue about Flipper Network.

For while, I commented

`initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())`

in this file
`/android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java`

## Solution 3

Whoever is still struggling with this issue. it's happening because of Flipper network plugin.
I disabled it and things work just fine.

My workaround to make this work is commenting out line number 43

```
38      NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
39      NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
40          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
41            @Override
42            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
43      //        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
44            }
45          });
46      client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
```

in this file `android/app/src/debug/java/com/**/ReactNativeFlipper.java`

## Solution 4

don't need to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

Need this:

```
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'}
            }
```

And I adjust your server,it works.

Comment: Solution 1: Yes, base url is correct. It has http, not using localhost, using ip only. As I mentioned in the question, it errors out only the first time I'm making the request. Basically in my app, I've a button which when clicked makes the api call. It errors out the first time. when I click the button again, the same api call works.
Solution 2 and 3 doesn't apply to me since I'm using expo. There is no android folder. Correct me If I'm wrong. I'm new to react-native
Solution 4: I do not understand what you mean. Could you be kind to explain?

Comment: @DrunkenDaddy can you provide reproducible example code from the GitHub repo? so I can fix it for you

Comment: Ah damn it, faced this error before but forgotten about it again. Works when I change `localhost` to my ip address; Eg `http:localhost:4000/api` -> `http:192.168.1.69:4000/api`

Comment: Changing localhost to IP address worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If someone doesn't like the upvoted answer or is still facing the issue, then my answer might help. Make sure your emulator/device time is same as real world time to avoid certificate validation error, otherwise manually set the correct time and reload the app.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is having trouble with this again.. I found that for android the ip needed to be 10.0.2.2 but for ios it needed to be 127.0.0.1.

The code below allows you to set them independently:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const LOCALHOST = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' : 'http://10.0.2.2:8000';
export const API_BASE_URL = LOCALHOST + '/api/v1/';
```

Comment: This worked for me. How did you even find this out lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to send an API request from an react native application using expo in a emulator to my rust actix web server.
After spending several hours into the issue and not being able to find the way to fix it, I found the solution in ngrok. It makes a tunnel from your local server to open web, so basically yo can call from your RN app to your api endpoint as if it would not be running in your localhost.

The error was fixed, instantly. Hope it helps, even if I am aware that is not a fix, but a workaround to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still experiencing this issue as of Nov 2023, and none of the solutions here works.

Using FileSystem's uploadAsync works perfectly, only downside to this is that it doesn't allow multiple file upload which is a deal breaker for me.

`npx expo install expo-file-system`

if you are only uploading a single file, then you could use this snippet

```js
import {uploadAsync} from "expo-file-system"
import axios from "axios"

let url = "" // your endpoint
let image = {} //imagePickerResult;
let sendData = {} // Plain object
let formData = new FormData(); // sendData  keys and values appended to formdata plus the image
 
if (Platform.OS == "android") {
    let res = await uploadAsync(url, image.uri, {
        fieldName: "nameOfField", 
        httpMethod: "PATCH", 
        mimeType: "image/*", 
        uploadType: FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART, 
        headers: {
            // access token bearears auth and what-not
        }, 
        parameters: sendData // This would be the BODY of the request
    })
    return res
} else {
    let res = await axios.patch(url, formData);

    return res
}
```